# How to fix warning "The 'u' format is deprecated" when using jellyfish package

Tags: python

I am writing a Python script to do name matching. For that I want to use the jellyfish module. But when I run this code:

```
import jellyfish as jf

a = "test"
b = "tast"

distance = jf.damerau_levenshtein_distance(a, b)

print(distance)
```

I get this warning:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/Python/WPy64-31001/notebooks/test.py", line 6
    distance = jf.damerau_levenshtein_distance(a, b)
DeprecationWarning: getargs: The 'u' format is deprecated. Use 'U' instead.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's a warning. You can use the package just fine.

Comment: Which versions of Python and jellyfish are you using? This might be interesting for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a warning. You can use the package just fine.

If you don't care to see the warning, you can set up a [Python warning filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html).

This has been addressed in https://github.com/jamesturk/jellyfish/issues/131 / https://github.com/jamesturk/cjellyfish/pull/12 and will likely be released in the next version of Jellyfish.